# The tag [uk] should be a synonym for [united-kingdom]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [uk](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) (currently 8 questions, no tag excerpt) should probably be a synonym for the tag [united-kingdom](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) (currently 216 questions, with tag excerpt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask and ye shall receive. This seems fairly uncontroversial and has been done.